# How to use random.sample() and not get `ValueError` exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

The goal is to give start and end limit and the # of numbers to generate. For instance I want to generate 100 random numbers between 1-100.

How do I make sure that I don't get `ValueError` exception?

The code I am using is:

```
nums = random.sample(range(1000, 2000), 1999)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

```
>>> nums = random.sample(range(1000, 2000), 1999)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 317, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

Your `range()` only holds 1000 elements:

```
>>> len(range(1000, 2000))
1000
```

`random.sample()` takes **unique values** from an input sequence, and thus can only pick up to `len(input)` elements in the first place. There are only 1000 unique values in your `range()`, you can't pick nearly 2000 unique values in random order from that.

If you wanted to generate 100 random numbers between two values, don't use `sample()`. Use a list comprehension and [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) or [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
```

This will produce 100 random numbers, repetitions allowed.

Even if repetition isn't allowed, to produce a sample of N elements out of a population of N it is better to use a *random shuffle*:

```
# the numbers 1 - 101, randomly distributed
result = list(range(1, 101))
random.shuffle(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)? It will give you every element of the range exactly once, in a random order:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = list(range(1000,2000))
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[1096, 1434, 1564, 1503, 1213, 1484, 1340, 1729, 1262, 1663, 1684, 1609, 1464, 1902, 1302, 1767, 1860, 1733, 1009, 1735, 1445, 1429, 1448, 1665, 1551, 1426, 1755, 1790, 1108, 1891, 1121, 1325, 1600, 1230, 1315, 1191, 1243, 1074, 1107, 1865, 1179, 1198, 1169, 1830, 1798, 1727, 1147, 1890, 1092, 1451, 1048, 1638, 1598, 1888, 1807, 1324, 1682, 1589, 1884, 1433, 1130, 1348, 1662, 1215, 1444, 1387, 1897, 1758, 1043, 1372, 1155, 1032, 1487, 1509, 1806, 1602, 1093, 1220, 1772, 1531, 1804, 1746, 1292, 1694, 1556, 1517, 1943, 1582, 1547, 1989, 1966, 1915, 1833, 1276, 1988, 1887, 1320, 1339, 1605, 1951, 1040, 1327, 1336, 1128, 1757, 1538, 1131, 1116, 1142, 1960, 1250, 1307, 1595, 1139, 1576, 1059, 1627, 1633, 1639, 1438, 1252, 1584, 1090, 1272, 1353, 1683, 1163, 1773, 1004, 1658, 1174, 1617, 1516, 1008, 1707, 1083, 1094, 1987, 1628, 1437, 1095, 1763, 1159, 1976, 1267, 1916, 1311, 1091, 1498, 1623, 1029, 1532, 1175, 1458, 1256, 1439, 1452, 1018, 1706, 1205, 1546, 1047, 1103, 1922, 1977, 1895, 1972, 1586, 1447, 1383, 1687, 1822, 1796, 1769, 1664, 1859, 1699, 1322, 1672, 1390, 1360, 1435, 1995, 1753, 1469, 1309, 1208, 1747, 1999, 1791, 1061, 1572, 1245, 1965, 1760, 1601, 1852, 1853, 1913, 1072, 1528, 1530, 1782, 1958, 1342, 1105, 1453, 1416, 1185, 1737, 1015, 1244, 1800, 1366, 1739, 1373, 1533, 1505, 1964, 1996, 1731, 1622, 1742, 1847, 1720, 1263, 1568, 1971, 1667, 1591, 1545, 1953, 1686, 1112, 1935, 1461, 1436, 1894, 1920, 1391, 1673, 1650, 1482, 1197, 1314, 1613, 1479, 1527, 1352, 1186, 1467, 1834, 1948, 1878, 1011, 1911, 1087, 1264, 1333, 1323, 1776, 1266, 1907, 1178, 1284, 1580, 1697, 1857, 1050, 1548, 1974, 1869, 1358, 1190, 1679, 1411, 1539, 1033, 1073, 1308, 1693, 1986, 1165, 1925, 1485, 1085, 1579, 1021, 1055, 1762, 1456, 1088, 1480, 1318, 1357, 1862, 1736, 1752, 1992, 1793, 1006, 1492, 1670, 1392, 1819, 1478, 1481, 1488, 1968, 1583, 1377, 1431, 1880, 1258, 1581, 1007, 1929, 1512, 1775, 1783, 1418, 1511, 1259, 1631, 1328, 1770, 1189, 1963, 1651, 1523, 1829, 1054, 1629, 1596, 1825, 1052, 1768, 1814, 1874, 1843, 1759, 1066, 1151, 1671, 1064, 1780, 1347, 1138, 1794, 1883, 1647, 1867, 1820, 1402, 1973, 1278, 1471, 1653, 1058, 1680, 1975, 1850, 1678, 1304, 1774, 1026, 1691, 1802, 1698, 1146, 1065, 1268, 1111, 1351, 1202, 1045, 1168, 1717, 1677, 1039, 1980, 1502, 1882, 1081, 1407, 1288, 1397, 1848, 1188, 1840, 1721, 1723, 1514, 1158, 1218, 1898, 1616, 1184, 1961, 1424, 1298, 1858, 1955, 1115, 1560, 1506, 1160, 1849, 1356, 1271, 1640, 1636, 1350, 1908, 1473, 1338, 1044, 1474, 1419, 1518, 1370, 1618, 1194, 1614, 1078, 1305, 1513, 1801, 1341, 1313, 1280, 1013, 1702, 1625, 1421, 1070, 1923, 1928, 1257, 1554, 1912, 1173, 1504, 1209, 1612, 1765, 1031, 1216, 1084, 1641, 1566, 1905, 1071, 1959, 1881, 1389, 1486, 1369, 1779, 1983, 1134, 1157, 1713, 1167, 1354, 1799, 1001, 1688, 1388, 1207, 1030, 1846, 1143, 1104, 1180, 1154, 1690, 1060, 1228, 1468, 1681, 1097, 1931, 1120, 1101, 1002, 1877, 1635, 1938, 1604, 1590, 1379, 1795, 1398, 1868, 1126, 1201, 1152, 1851, 1620, 1899, 1854, 1892, 1106, 1203, 1156, 1214, 1703, 1425, 1269, 1226, 1812, 1549, 1766, 1422, 1316, 1740, 1573, 1321, 1606, 1692, 1875, 1056, 1477, 1709, 1632, 1611, 1381, 1297, 1542, 1967, 1708, 1124, 1936, 1051, 1384, 1440, 1196, 1969, 1615, 1689, 1571, 1940, 1685, 1277, 1335, 1326, 1077, 1654, 1193, 1751, 1069, 1212, 1299, 1310, 1508, 1399, 1529, 1954, 1408, 1042, 1561, 1211, 1119, 1587, 1086, 1855, 1466, 1067, 1192, 1441, 1918, 1507, 1624, 1607, 1553, 1217, 1362, 1592, 1206, 1900, 1608, 1450, 1273, 1150, 1823, 1396, 1337, 1349, 1265, 1187, 1306, 1909, 1500, 1652, 1172, 1749, 1057, 1866, 1099, 1003, 1079, 1552, 1363, 1385, 1861, 1863, 1567, 1455, 1594, 1831, 1603, 1784, 1956, 1319, 1557, 1223, 1359, 1842, 1962, 1378, 1153, 1979, 1950, 1491, 1826, 1063, 1177, 1725, 1933, 1738, 1838, 1233, 1599, 1927, 1788, 1080, 1301, 1137, 1132, 1409, 1024, 1110, 1835, 1014, 1993, 1845, 1290, 1470, 1162, 1199, 1183, 1239, 1465, 1715, 1985, 1332, 1569, 1903, 1365, 1423, 1889, 1412, 1176, 1432, 1734, 1803, 1016, 1181, 1118, 1254, 1075, 1114, 1161, 1037, 1871, 1593, 1270, 1495, 1982, 1082, 1401, 1659, 1970, 1261, 1939, 1229, 1496, 1914, 1832, 1519, 1919, 1166, 1816, 1646, 1904, 1312, 1113, 1540, 1375, 1577, 1634, 1330, 1946, 1565, 1382, 1695, 1253, 1499, 1520, 1716, 1544, 1543, 1287, 1619, 1371, 1710, 1027, 1655, 1750, 1610, 1443, 1034, 1260, 1334, 1778, 1525, 1403, 1219, 1246, 1836, 1428, 1756, 1522, 1235, 1010, 1675, 1578, 1873, 1251, 1570, 1952, 1023, 1462, 1515, 1761, 1805, 1744, 1626, 1701, 1020, 1764, 1901, 1637, 1117, 1394, 1413, 1000, 1649, 1906, 1242, 1674, 1490, 1395, 1049, 1355, 1344, 1917, 1076, 1787, 1574, 1041, 1127, 1910, 1893, 1415, 1476, 1771, 1555, 1102, 1317, 1283, 1998, 1558, 1343, 1732, 1232, 1406, 1785, 1997, 1668, 1144, 1661, 1122, 1164, 1248, 1291, 1149, 1811, 1224, 1380, 1300, 1949, 1125, 1719, 1286, 1711, 1984, 1296, 1068, 1129, 1841, 1588, 1856, 1182, 1676, 1879, 1274, 1240, 1896, 1459, 1449, 1712, 1430, 1501, 1019, 1483, 1140, 1981, 1510, 1648, 1696, 1225, 1025, 1524, 1754, 1417, 1808, 1642, 1247, 1741, 1704, 1046, 1241, 1926, 1038, 1255, 1944, 1295, 1537, 1028, 1657, 1700, 1289, 1942, 1100, 1827, 1279, 1427, 1135, 1062, 1563, 1281, 1446, 1886, 1494, 1285, 1195, 1885, 1828, 1728, 1934, 1990, 1726, 1924, 1526, 1303, 1222, 1669, 1809, 1786, 1978, 1921, 1777, 1536, 1275, 1405, 1813, 1364, 1991, 1136, 1237, 1714, 1035, 1098, 1597, 1238, 1475, 1022, 1249, 1666, 1463, 1493, 1123, 1472, 1234, 1109, 1170, 1345, 1781, 1145, 1724, 1393, 1656, 1722, 1839, 1621, 1200, 1660, 1957, 1870, 1442, 1945, 1941, 1748, 1386, 1585, 1171, 1133, 1005, 1535, 1346, 1017, 1745, 1797, 1329, 1792, 1404, 1630, 1293, 1872, 1930, 1367, 1227, 1815, 1294, 1844, 1454, 1204, 1460, 1994, 1368, 1410, 1550, 1148, 1562, 1236, 1810, 1374, 1575, 1282, 1331, 1743, 1821, 1818, 1876, 1414, 1947, 1141, 1645, 1089, 1817, 1705, 1012, 1541, 1824, 1420, 1361, 1231, 1489, 1053, 1534, 1837, 1643, 1400, 1730, 1644, 1937, 1210, 1864, 1376, 1036, 1457, 1497, 1718, 1221, 1521, 1559, 1789, 1932]
```